# counting words with domDocument class

Tags: php, domdocument

How can i counting the words in a html page, with domDocument?

for example, if the input is something like:

```
    <div> Hello something open. <a href="open.php">click</a> 
    lorem ipsum <a href="open.php">here></a>
```

the output:
Number Word
1 Hello
2 something
3 open
4 click
5 lorem
6 ipsum
7 here.

And what if i need only the linktext?
click 4
here 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this for the entire document, it is likely easier to just [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and then run [`str_word_count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) on the result.

If you have to do this with DOM, you can do

```
$str = <<< HTML
<div> Hello something open. <a href="open.php">click</a>
lorem ipsum <a href="open.php">here></a></div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()');

$textNodeContent = '';
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $textNodeContent .= " $node->nodeValue";
}
print_r(str_word_count( $textNodeContent, 1 ));
```

Using `text()` as the [XPath expression](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) will only give you the textnodes in the document. You can limit this to just return the link texts with `//a/text()` for the expression.

Comment: Thanks, and what should I do if I want to count the words before the links? example before the first link 3 words, before the second links 6 words

Comment: @turbod in that case you'd have to iterate over the Nodes with DOM.